# json parse error unrecognized token ' <' react native while hashing in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, react-native

I'm trying to insert a hashed password using sha2 into a mySQL table from a React Native app with the following code:

```
connection.query(
            "INSERT INTO user(username, email, password) SELECT (?, ?, ?)",
                [username, email, SHA2(password, 512)], function (err, result) {

                if (err) {
                    res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'Could not connect' });
                }
                else{
                    res.send({ 'success': true, 'message': 'User created' });
                }
        });
```

It works fine when I take out the hashing and change SELECT to VALUES, but once I add the SHA2 function the app crashes giving me the error "json parse error unrecognized token ' <'". I suspect something is wrong with my syntax but I can't pin point what it is.

Comment: Does the password contain that character?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for `INSERT ... SELECT`. Check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)